# How to get all installs and uninstalls shops names with shopify API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to get a list of all installed / uninstalled shops urls of my app.
I look at the API and didn't find an answer:(

thank you for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

Obviously when a shop installs, you can save that for permanent use. When a Shopify uninstalls, you can save that for permanent use. There is no API calls that will give you that data AFAIK. Just do it yourself if you want that info at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a list of all your merchants overtime via Shopify Partners Dashboard (https://partners.shopify.com/)
If you export the current merchants, you will be able to see all the merchants' store names and shop URLs too.
For more info check https://shopify.dev/apps/store/success/tracking-usage